# How to resize polygon in svg?

Tags: svg

I am trying to resize the svg polygon elements, depending on the svg element.

Suppose I have an svg element of width and height of 500 each, but in some cases polygon element x y points will go out of the height and width of the svg element. Is it possible to resize the polygon to fit in the svg element?

Here is my code in jsbin http://jsbin.com/iXUPeLu/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the bounding rectangles of all the polygon elements in an SVG is easy enough. Just use the `getBBox()` function inside a loop as follows:

```
var o = document.getElementById('theSVG');
var s = o.getElementsByTagName('polygon');
minx = miny = 1e100;
maxx = maxy = -minx;
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    var x = s[i].getBBox();
    if (x.x < minx) minx = x.x;
    if (x.y < miny) miny = x.y;
    if (x.x + x.width > maxx) maxx = x.x + x.width;
    if (x.y + x.height > maxy) maxy = x.y + x.height;
}
```

To scale the SVG image based on the results, it looks like you have to transform each of the polygons individually. (Setting a transform attribute for the top-level `<svg>` element doesn't seem to work.)

```
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    var m = s[i].getCTM();
    m = m.scale(scale).translate(-minx, -miny);
    s[i].setAttribute("transform", "matrix(" + m.a + "," + m.b + "," + m.c + "," + m.d + "," + m.e + "," + m.f + ")");
}
```

You can see it working here: [**Link to JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BS9tF/)

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is working in width and height of 500px. But when I change the width to 1000 and height of 500 some part is getting cut off. Can you help me? Here is the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/BS9tF/2/

Comment: Oops, change `var scaley = width / (maxy - miny);` to `var scaley = height / (maxy - miny);`

Comment: Your code is very much helpful to me. But I didn't understand a single line of code you have written. Can you comment your code in fiddle so that I can understand and learn from the code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `transform="scale(0.5)"` for example. Example [here](http://jsbin.com/EnIQABU/1/edit).

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically calculate the scale factor. For example if some polygon element need scale factor of 0.1 to fit in the svg element, so what do I do in that case?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you're generating those polygons. If you're using Javascript, you could get the bounding box using `.getBBox()` and, by comparing that to the size of the SVG, compute the scale factor.